# how do iterate through the hidden field value for each row in a table using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, json.net

i have a table which displays all users and the id for each user is stored in hidden field, i want to be able to get the value stored in the hidden on button click event using Ajax or Jquery. Code below:

```
foreach (var del in approvedList)
 {         
   <tr>
    <td>@del.CampaignName</td>
    <td>@del.Name</td>                           
    <td>@del.ApprovalStatus</td>                            
    <td>  
    <div id="hiddenWrapper" class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="@del.PayoutId" />
          <input id="btnApprove" name="btnApprove" class="btn  btn-success" type="button" title="Approve" value="Approve" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("PayoutApproval", "Account", new { id = @del.PayoutId })'" />
      </div>                                                                
    </div>                                                                                        
  </td>
 </tr>
 }
```

And the query function is :

```
 <script>
    $('#btnApprove').click(function () {
    $("#btnApprove").prop("disabled", true);
    console.log("id field value: "+$("#id").val());
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Account/PayoutApproval',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: $("#id").val() }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',

        success: function (result) {

            if (result.f != null) {
                swal(result.f, "!", "error");
                $("#btnApprove").prop("disabled", false);

            } else {
                swal({
                    title: "Success!",
                    text: result.s,
                    type: "success"
                });
                $('#action').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");
                $("#submitBrdFrm").prop("disabled", true);
                top.location.href = workListUrl;
            }
        }

    });

    return false;
});
```

While logging the hidden field value, i realized i could only get the value for first row only, subsequent rows return null. I want to be able to get value for each row upon button click, this is my challenge, i am new to front end development.

Comment: You haven't worded what you want to do very well, but what I don't understand is, why are you using an ajax call?

Let all the hidden values render and once the document is ready then grab the hidden value from the input.

If you want a universal function that works for everything then look into traversing with .parent() .prev() .next() .closest() .find() and .val() in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to add hidden input just use data attr on button `data-id="@del.PayoutId"` and bind it to id field
as following sample:

```
foreach (var del in approvedList)
 { 
 <tr>
    <td>@del.CampaignName</td>
    <td>@del.Name</td>                           
    <td>@del.ApprovalStatus</td>                            
    <td>                       
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input data-id="@del.PayoutId" name="btnApprove" class="btn  btn-success approvebtn" type="button" title="Approve" value="Approve" />
      </div>                                                                
    </div>                                                                                        
  </td>  
</tr>
}
```

you can handle click on approve as following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.approvebtn').click(function (e) {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    console.log("id field value: "+$(this).data('id'));
     // add your code here
    return false;
   });   
 });
```

you can get clicked id using `$(this).data('id')`

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have tried your answer, but still getting the id of the first row only!

Comment: did you use same selector  $('.approvebtn').click(function (e) {}); for bind click event